# Is there a plotting library which allows me to drill down and roll up on a social network type graph?

Tags: graphs, data-analysis, analytics, plotting

I want to plot a social network for linkage analysis. Very specifically, I have a dataset with call data showing who interacted whom at what time.

In the resulting interactive graph, I should be able to (preferably) click on one node to look into it's neighbors only (all other nodes and edges get hidden). I should be able to do this recursively. This is equivalent to a drill-down procedure. I should then be able to roll-up to reveal the parent view to my current view.

As an example, consider the following network

[image]

Lets say I clicked on "C". The result should be

[image]

Now, I can click on "I" to view only its network and so forth. At all stages, it is possible to return to the view that came before current view.

What are the recommended plotting libraries for recreation of this requirement? The most popular libraries in Python and R don't have this particular feature, as far as I could see.

Comment: "Click" in what? Are you looking to develop a desktop app, or something for the browser? If desktop, which o/s? Must the solution be free, or do you have a budget? The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: The product would be a webapp. By clicking, I mean clicking on the node object (the circle object). Preferably open source solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It is clear what you meant by clicking, but wasn't clear if you were clicking in the browser, etc? You might want to edit your question, as not everyone will read these comments.  By `webapp`, you do mean running in the browser, don't you? I was confused by the mention of Python & R, unless you are generating the graphics server side, which I might not do unless the graph is huge. For a desktop app, I would go straight to [GraphViz]( http://www.graphviz.org/). Maybe you can do something with http://www.webgraphviz.com/ ?